# How to export a collection from mongo using terminal

Tags: mongodb

I want to export the whole data from one of my collections in mongodb to a csv file.

This is how my db looks like:

```
"Tags",
"checkouts",
"imports",
"products"
```

I am trying to export "checkouts".

I am connected to the db through the terminal and I tried the following commands:

```
mongoexport --db nameofdatabase  --collection checkouts  --out coll.json

mongoexport --db nameofdatabase  --collection checkouts  --type=csv --fields  --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

The error message I get after running both commands command is : "Unexpected identifier"

Comment: You should first exit from  mongo shell and give above commands..

Comment: Also in your second attempt you never specified a field to include in the export.

Answer (score 0):

MongoExport cannot be used in the mongo shell. It is a terminal command like mongo.